# I am trying to get data from room database in arraylist but it shows only last record in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-room

I have room database in android. but when i am retrieving data from database and showing in expandable `RecyclerView` it shows only last records in my child list. there is one child  `ArrayList` under the parent `ArrayList`.

I am adding data from database in `hashmap` in the key and value format in `ExpandableListView`

```
        HashMap<String, List<Movies>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<Movies>>();
        ArrayList<String> moviecategoriess = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            childDataItems = new ArrayList<>();
            String movieCategory = tasks.get(i).getMovieCategory();

            String moviename = tasks.get(i).getMovieName();

            String description = tasks.get(i).getMovieDescription();
            String bannerimage = tasks.get(i).getMovieImage();
            //   String maincat=expandableListDetail.get("").get(i).
            childDataItems.add(new Movies(moviename, bannerimage, description));

            expandableListDetail.put(movieCategory, childDataItems);
            moviecategoriess.add(movieCategory);
        }

        Iterator it = expandableListDetail.entrySet().iterator();

        final ArrayList<MovieCategory> movieCategories = new ArrayList();

        moviesArrayList = new ArrayList();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String name = pairs.getKey().toString();
            moviesArrayList = (ArrayList<Movies>) pairs.getValue();

            movieCategories.add(new MovieCategory(name, moviesArrayList));
        }
        moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MovieActivity.this, movieCategories);
        Functions.setDatatoRecyclerView(rv_movies_list, moviesAdapter, MovieActivity.this);
        moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I want to show data in `ArrayList` like this

Parent Item: Thriller

ChildItems In List:

1) Force2

2) Sarkar2

Parent Item: Action

ChildItems In List:

1) Border

2) Battlefield

Comment: Can you watch values of "expandableListDetail" and "moviecategoriess" in debug? Maybe you have issues with your UI, try to load this data in another empty layout just with RecyclerView in it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case problem is with for loop each time you run for loop a new array list is created as per your code so simply replace your code with this:

```
HashMap<String, List<Movies>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<Movies>>();
        ArrayList<String> moviecategoriess = new ArrayList<>();
childDataItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            String movieCategory = tasks.get(i).getMovieCategory();

            String moviename = tasks.get(i).getMovieName();

            String description = tasks.get(i).getMovieDescription();
            String bannerimage = tasks.get(i).getMovieImage();
            //   String maincat=expandableListDetail.get("").get(i).
            childDataItems.add(new Movies(moviename, bannerimage, description));

            expandableListDetail.put(movieCategory, childDataItems);
            moviecategoriess.add(movieCategory);
        }
```

Comment: but in this case same data is getting in childitem list.

Comment: Did you try this change?